# How do I query the records using Miva

Tags: php, sql

so i have a product in a system called miva

I can get to this product just fine but i have another page that describes many products on one page and i need to either query the database for their information or somehow get all the information needed. I have no idea how do you that with this Miva site and where it even stores all these products once created in the miva admin

Comment: I have an in-depth understanding of the (antiquated) Miva scripting language and server configuration if you or anyone ever needs help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used PHP my admin to get the db info and queried the appropriate table